# DocuSign - Multiple Radio groups with conditionals

Tags: c#, docusignapi

We stumbled across a requirement where we need multiple radio groups but only one time yes can be selected. But I don't see an option how to group the controls.

So, the data is in a list with multiple actions. I am programmatically creating radio groups with Yes or no options for each action. Requirement here is, if one action is accepted as Yes, remaining groups below cannot be selected as Yes. I want to show a validation in that scenario.

[image: Sample Image]

I tried an option with creating textboxes for each group and calculating the value of radio button value. But, docusign doesn't have radio button value in Formula bar.

Is there something I can use for this scenario.

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup
        {
            GroupName = "Accepted",
            DocumentId = "1",
            Radios = new List<Radio>(),
        };

        radioGroup.Radios.Add(new Radio { AnchorString = "Action1", PageNumber = "2", Value = "Yes", AnchorXOffset = "282", AnchorYOffset = "-02" });
        radioGroup.Radios.Add(new Radio { AnchorString = "Action1", PageNumber = "2", Value = "No", AnchorXOffset = "323", AnchorYOffset = "-02" });
```

P.s: As it deviates from the UI for user, I cannot use a dropdown/checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign doesn't have something that will exactly address this but there are a few options that you could try.

First, you could use [conditional tabs](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/tabs-deep-dive-conditional-tabs) and only show the second set of radio groups if the user selects "no" on the first set. That way if they select "yes" in the first radio group, they will be restricted from selecting in the second group.

A second option is that if the user can only select "yes" for one of the radio groups, you could just use one radio group with one radio button placed next to each action where the user is only allowed to choose one action rather than choosing "yes" or "no" for each one.

Comment: Wow. I think this approach might fit. Let me check how it works and will update here.